# Difference between jinja2 functions and filters?

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I am writing some functions to do things like format dates and text in my templates.

```
def coolfunc(s):
    return s + ' is cool'

 app.jinja_env.globals.update(coolfunc=coolfunc)
 app.jinja_env.filters['coolfunc'] = coolfunc
```

template:

```
{{ coolfunc(member.name) }}
{{ member.name | coolfunc }}
```

output:

```
John is cool
John is cool
```

I am not sure what the real difference between functions and filters are. It seems to me that filters just look cleaner?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The difference is that filters can have special access to the `Environment` or `Context`, but regular (global) functions cannot;  specifically, there's [`contextfilter`](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/api/#utilities) and friends.  This can be useful for doing context sensitive things like localization and formatting, without depending on global state.

http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/api/#utilities

Comment: Reading the Jinja documentation it seems that `@contextfilter` and `@contextfunction` gives the same opportunities? Are there any real differences apart from the syntax when using them?

Comment: @bohrax i think the only difference is that one gives a filter and the other gives a function.  In jinja2, they are syntactically different at the template level: filters are used as `{{ foo | myfilter (bar, baz) }}` but functions are `{{ myfunction (foo, bar, baz) }}`.  adding a normal python funciton to the `Environment` will not automatically give it these context power, its neccesary to add the decorator.